# Load content and preload images via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, load

Say I have like:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var h = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load(h);
    });
});
```

That actually doesn't load the images as well it just loads the content, how do you go about loading the actual images too?

Some people didn't seem to understand: what I mean is it does load the images but doesn't 'preload' thus meaning you witness the images load individually.

**Edit**: Say the href was equal to somepage.html and that page had images on it as well as content, yes it would load the images and the content but it doesn't actually preload the images at all, you're still witnessing the images load individually. How would one go about preloading the images in the request itself?

Comment: There's no reason why any `img` tags loaded from the url at `$(this).attr('href')` shouldn't load the image. Do you get any errors in your error console (or JavaScript console, depending on browser)?

Comment: @SimpleCoder I guess you don't fully understand the nature of the question, yes the images are loaded in but not 'preloaded' thus meaning you're witnessing the images load.

Comment: Are the images using a relative path in their `src`, that might not be pointing to the right file from the html page in which you've `load()`-ed the content?

Comment: You should have specified that you want to preload the images. As it stands now, the question is worded a little confusingly.

Comment: So the images get called in the onready `$(function()` which fires after the page is loaded and you want the images loaded before onready?

Comment: @SimpleCoder I think we were all just insulted. I find that ludicrous since the OP stated: `That actually doesn't load the images as well it just loads the content, how do you go about loading the actual images too?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

1. Hide the `#content` div, and call `load` on it. This will load the content invisibly so your users don't see the images load afterwards
2. Bind `load` event handlers on each image, and when they have all fired, re-show the `#content` div

See this answer for reference: [Know when images are done loading in AJAX response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658216/jquery-know-when-images-are-done-loading-in-ajax-response/1658245#1658245). It will show you exactly what to do.

Comment: Interesting approach, let me test this out a second. Thanks.

Comment: Does he have to bind a separate event handler for each image? Wouldn't `$('#content').load(function(){...});` let him know when all the images have loaded? Note: I'm not talking about jQuery's AJAX load method. That's what he uses to load in that HTML with the images. I'm talking about the overloaded `load` function: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/. This will fire after all elements withing `#content` have fully loaded...

Comment: He will still need to bind a handler to each image. I don't think that adding an event handler onto `#content` will work, since the `load` event doesn't bubble up.

Answer (score 1):

See the worked example here on how to preload your images;

http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript