# After using ajax to change element, how to detect if the new content has been fully loaded?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<div class="content">Some original Text<img src="someImage"></div>

$.ajax('someAjaxUrl', function(data){
    $('content').html(data);
})
```

I'm using some codes similar to above to get content from server and display it in the content area. The actual content contains lots of images and text, so after the ajax request is completed and the HTML has been changed, it still takes some time to render all the images. I'm trying to catch the event when all the new contents have been fully loaded including the images:

```
$.ajax('someAjaxUrl', function(data){
    $('content').html(data);
    $('content')[0].addEventListener('load',function(){
      // Do something
    })
})
```

But this seems not working. Is this possible?

Comment: If you could accept my answer, assuming it works for you, that'd be cool. I'm heading to bed now since it's pretty late where I am. If you're still struggling when I come on next I'll let you know of any other possible solutions.

Comment: Think this thread is dealing with the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658216/know-when-images-are-done-loading-in-ajax-response/1658245#1658245

Comment: Did you try `.ajaxStop`? 
https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/?

Comment: Did this not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you run:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// AJAX, etc in here ...
});
```

You can do anything inside the function WHEN the document has loaded.

**Edit:**

If you're running the AJAX after the page had already loaded, you can place them into something like this:

```
<div id="loaded" style="display: none">
<img src""/>
<p>Whatever you want in here.</p>
<img src""/>
<img src""/>
<img src""/>
</div>
```

**Then in your jQuery:**

```
$('#loaded img').load(function(){
$('#loaded').show()
});
```

Comment: Put that within your AJAX request and the 'loaded' div will only be displayed once the images are loaded.

Comment: You'd essentially be preventing the user from seeing the loading of images, they'd be displayed when loaded.

Comment: Sorry, I defined loaded as a class. Edited.

Comment: On this page http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ it says 'load' event "Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache". It is a little hard to test but I am wondering if the users click back and forth then there will be some images that have already been in the cache, which will make the 'load' event cease to fire. This is problematic because I will hide the new content until the 'load' event fires, any solution for this?

Comment: What is the most ideal outcome for you when the user loads the page? I thought we were just preventing the user from seeing the rendering of images?

Comment: I personally would add an animated load in screen that disappears when the images have loaded

Comment: If I've helped at all could you vote my suggestion up please.